# Computing time in Python [Python for Data Analysis 3E]

Tags: python, numpy, time

In [Chapter 4 of Python for Data Analysis 3E](https://wesmckinney.com/book/numpy-basics.html), it shows the following example and claims that numpy should be much faster.

[image]

**However, when I tried it myself, I got very different results as circled below where numpy actually takes longer time. Could anyone help clarify what the author means in the book, please?**

[image]

Comment: You just need to not ignore what it shows you.

Comment: @KellyBundy is right but a little cryptic. Look at the number of loops timeit used in each case.

Comment: @JonSG Do you mean the time per loop? How come each loop takes less time but overall run time is higher?

Comment: The reason many module functions are supposed to work faster than python reproduced equivalent code is that many of the module function are written in C or Cython (a C/python hybrid). C is a lower level pre-compiled language whereas python is scripting language. That means python "compiles" or more accurately interprets code on the fly - which is much slower. C is lightning fast to execute compared to python

Comment: @GalodoLeste I understand what you are saying. But I guess it is only a general rule? Hence, it doesn't work in this particular example? Sorry if I missed anything.

Comment: It is always possible that you can come up with a more efficient code than official module methods as you may not need to handle a lot of overheads the module might have to. Often the module methods need to cater to everyone needs whereas you obviously only need to cater to yours. And that may mean you have leaner code. Can't say in this case though as I am not familiar with the underlying code of numpy

Answer (score 4):

You should read the actual results, not what you circled. NumPy was faster, 0.9 ms vs 55.6 ms. The benchmark for NumPy took longer because it repeated 100x more often (1000 loops instead of 10 loops).